# goBack button while preserving url state using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, html5-history

Just for the record, I am still using react-router 0.13.x. Ok, so this is what I am trying to do:

I have master view (grid) and a detail view. In the detail view there are two tabs (each tab is a route inside the item). Something like:

```
grid/
 item/
    tab/
    tab/
```

The grid can have a query in the url in this way: http://url.com/grid?sort=name

Inside the grid component we can change the sort and that will be reflected into the URL. What I want to implement is a back button inside the `<Item/>` component.

I tried with `goBack()` from react-router but I have two main problems:

- If user clicks on a tab inside the `<Item/>` component, the `goBack()` function will go back to the previous tab, not to the `<Grid/>` (that is normal of course, but not what I want here).
- If user refreshes the page while seeing the `<Item/>` component, clicking goBack will say:

`Warning: goBack() was ignored because there is no router history`

Next try, using `getCurrentRoutes()`:

`this.context.router.transitionTo(routes[routes.length-2].path);`

The problem with this is that the user will lost its `sort` selection for the `<Grid />`. So if user change the sort to surname: http://url.com/grid?sort=surname, clicks into an item and use the back button, he will be back to the default route: http://url.com/grid?sort=name. This won't happen if user uses the native browser back button, even if the user refreshes the `<Item/>` page, clicking the native back button will bring the user to the `<Grid/>` with the correct sort query.

I guess what I am basically looking here is a goBack() that goes back to the parent route (`<Grid/>` in this case) ignoring internal routes from `<Tab/>` and then a way to preserve the url query while going back to the `<Grid/>`.

Any ideas on how to do achieve something better that I did here?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the current query params (which can be accessed from `this.props.location.query`) in the Location object when transitioning to the next tab as in :

```
   // go to next tab
   this.context.router.push({
     pathname:'/tab2', 
     query: this.props.location.query})
   // go back
   this.context.router.push({
     pathname: routes[routes.length-2].path, // your grid path
     query: this.props.location.query})
```

Hope it helps.